# Textures Not Rendering Blender 2.8

Tags: texturing

I can't get my textures to render on this model.  The materials are assigned and the shader nodes are hooked up.  I think.  It shows up when I view in solid mode with the color set to "texture" (2nd picture).  Won't show up in render view or lookdev.  Not sure what is going on, any advice??

UPDATE:

I do have a few other materials/textures patched up the same exact way and they seem to be working if that helps at all...

UPDATE: picture of UV mapped correctly, right? shows texture only in solid mode w/ texture color.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: why are you connecting the _Color_ output of the second texture node to the _Alpha_ input? You should connect _Alpha_ to _Alpha_

Comment: thanks for the correction! doesn't solve problem, though, same issue...??

Comment: Can you share the .blend file?

Comment: updated post with link!

Comment: I'm sorry, the .blend file is not working (it might have been a corrupted file?). Please check that your file is saved properly and share it on Blender Exchange https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Also, be sure to pack all the textures and other assets in the .blend file before saving

Comment: Sorry about that! Reuploaded to blendexchange w/ textures...should work now.

Comment: It looks to me like you didn't do any uv unwrapping and you just added multiple textures to different parts of the same mesh. That's not how you do it. You want to have one texture per mesh in the end. And if you want to add texture you need to unwrap your mesh first and then tell blender where your textures go.

Comment: when i select everything that the eye_brown.001 is assigned to (the eyes) and view its base color image ("brown_eye.png"), the UV editor it shows the unwrapped mesh mapping on to the image of the eyes, no? like in the first picture above, or you can see in the .blend file.  i may be completely misunderstanding something here but i thought that that is what needs to happen for the material to display.  it's telling blender where to map on via those spider-web type vertex points on the UV editor.  EDIT: and i just double checked; there's only one material assigned to those eyes.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why they don't show up is that the UV unwrap is not done properly.

If you select the eyes in **Edit Mode**, you can see that the vertices are all in the bottom right corner, where the texture is transparent (so there is no color data). To change that, just position the vertices on the eyes in the texture and you are all set!

This is what you have right now (the wrong way):

[image]

And this is the right way:

[image]

Comment: bizarre, that's not even what shows up on mine.  mine shows the spider web like you have on both eyes! see the first picture i uploaded.  that's not what shows up when you check in the .blend file? what tool did you use to select the eyes? i'm just grabbing the eyes from the material assignment.  updated original post to show you what i mean.

Comment: Your first image and my first image are the same, the only difference is that my UVs are highlighted, so they are orange. To select your UV, select the eyes in the viewport, then in the **UV Editor** press A (_select all_) or use the _box selection tool

Comment: You will see you UV becoming orange, like in my image. Press G to move them on the eye and scale them as needed.